# Cannot understand object with array as key

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I've found some wild code on the web i don't understand:

```
return Object.assign({}, state, {
  [action.subreddit]: posts(state[action.subreddit], action)
})
```

What is `[action.subreddit]` doing? I thought that object keys had to be strings but this appears to be an array?

I'm hoping to understand mechanically how this code works.

thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's not an array as key, it's the es6 way to use a variable (/ a computed property) as the key.
Consider this:

```
var a = "foo";
function getKey() { 
    return "myKey"; 
}

var obj = {
    [a] : "bar",
    [getKey()] : "baz"
};


console.log(obj.foo); // bar
console.log(obj.myKey) // baz
```

So `[action.subreddit]` just sets the key's name to whatever value `action.subreddit` is holding.

Comment: You can also use this notation to get the value of a key `console.log(obj[a]); // bar`.